# No service for type 'Sitecore.Messaging.GatewayService.GatewayServiceOptions' has been registered

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

I'm migrating the `Sitecore 9.1.1` site to `Sitecore 10.2` and encountered with below error. Any suggestion to fix this issue is helpful.

[image]

Comment: Try to compare configs and dll from upgraded 10.2 to vanilla 10.2 version, you might miss something.

Comment: I agree with @GauravAgarwal and I will suggest you to also check if anywhere in your solution, you need to register the service but it's not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an old file from `Sitecore 9.1.1` which might be  `Sitecore.Messaging.GatewayService.config`.
This file does not exist from `version 9.2` onward. I suggest that you delete this file and try again.

More importantly, you should compare clean `Sitecore 10.2` with your current Sitecore upgrade setup and see if there are any files that are from `9.1.1 version`. I recommend Kdiff 3 tool where you can choose two directories to compare their contents. Helps a lot to identify what is the difference in their folder contents.

Comment: Yes.. This was a issue. Actually in Sitecore 10.2 the DLL Sitecore.Messaging.GatewayService.config NO longer used. Deleting this dll solved this issue.